# What is static exception checking and dynamic exception checking?

Tags: java, exception

On an online forum someone mentioned Java's  static exception checking is not great and causes scalability and versioning problems.

I figured  a change in class function throwing new exception, breaking the client code could be attributed as versioning problem.  But I am not sure.

- What is the scalability problem with static exception checking ?
- What is the dynamic exception checking ?

Comment: Do you mean checked and unchecked Exception handling?

Comment: Presumably http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Dynamic_checking_of_exceptions

Comment: @Quoi : I don't know since I do know not if dynamic-exception checking is same as unchecked exception handling.

Comment: @MattBall :Wiki description for  dynamic-exception checking would imply it is simply a kind of s/w testing methodoloy. May be I missunderstood that section. Either way I am still looking for answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checked exceptions in Java can cause an scalability problem when programmers fail to throw exceptions suitable to the method. (See *Effective Java*, Item 43: *Throw exceptions appropriate to the abstraction*).

Lazy programmers tend to append exceptions to the `throws` clause of their method without considering whether they are appropriate. As a result, methods gather increasing numbers of exceptions as you look higher and higher in the application architecture. Top-level methods can throw ten or more exceptions if one is not careful.

For instance, in a method designed to encrypt data, many low-level exceptions could be thrown (e.g. `IOException`, `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, `KeyNotFoundException`...). It is not necessary to expose these to an API user. Instead, an `EncryptionFailed` exception could be thrown, with the gory details stored in the `cause` field of the exception.

---

I presume "dynamic exception checking" might refer to catching `Throwable` or `Exception` (one of the root classes) and dynamically deciding whether to handle the exception, based on some external stimulus. For example:

```
List<Class<?>> exceptionTypes = new ArrayList<>();
exceptionTypes.add(IllegalArgumentException.class);
exceptionTypes.add(IOException.class);

try {
  // do something
} catch (Exception e) {
  if (exceptionTypes.contains(e.getClass())) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Note: the above example is just an illustration. But imagine an IDE that executes code on behalf of the user and allows them to select exception classes they wish to catch.

Comment: Here's a context where the author is using "static" and "dynamic" when referring to exceptions: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that dynamic exception checking is just another name of firing exceptions at run-time.

Although I believe in static exception checking, Java way of static exception checking really has problems that concern interface implementations.

Say, we have `IParser`. What appropriate exceptions its method `parse()` may throw? Possibly `SyntaxErrorException`. Now we want a `ServerResponseParserFromURL` to be used in such a way:

```
class ServerResponseParserFromURL implements IParser { .... };
....
try {
   IParser parser = new ServerResponseParser(new URL("http://example.com/test.htm"));
   parser.parse();
   ....
}
```

Here is the problem — the implementation of `IParser` may fire, say, `NoRouteToHostException`. So we can not use nice and concise form and need to fallback to long form:

```
class ServerResponseParser implements IParser { .... };
....
try {
   String response = getServerResponse(new URL("http://example.com/test.htm"));
   IParser parser = new ServerResponseParser(response);
   parser.parse();
   ....
}
```

As you see, in practice, our `IParser` is `IStringParser`, not the generic `IParser`.

Although it may be tolerable in this particular case, it complicates things when we want to supply an `IParser` as one of arguments of a function `f`. Say, to be able to parse response of url-identified server, we can not just feed `ServerResponseParser` object and url — we need to find a way to feed `getServerResponse` method to `f`.